# Adding plugins.ts file in nuxt vuex module folder adds a 'plugins' state field

Tags: nuxt.js

It seems like Nuxt is adding any additional files beyond `index.js`, `state.js`, `mutations.js`, `getters.js` and `actions.js` to the state of the module.

Is there any way to stop Nuxt from doing so? I'd like to include a `plugins.js` file which has plugins defined relating to a specific module.

I have the following setup

- dir: store

  - index.js
  - dir: photos

    - state/mutations/getters/actions.js,
    - plugins.js

The plugins.js file defines a plugin which I import and includes in the index.js file

```js
// store/index.js
import { vuexPluginUploadPhotosOnLogin } from './photos/plugins'

export const plugins = [vuexPluginUploadPhotosOnLogin]
```

This setup works in as much as the plugin is set up correctly as is my store. But there is one small thing that bothers me, and it is this:

[image: Nuxt adds a plugin state field!]

That plugins state field is created by Nuxt because of the plugins.js file being in the mod directory. If I remove it, the state field is also removed.

Why does Nuxt do this? And is there a way to stop it?

I know I could hide the plugins file outside of the structure of the store, but... it really belongs there! It absolutely is the best home for it, and it is annoying to have to move the file somewhere else to satisfy Nuxt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to add how I got around this in the end. I simply added all the plugins in the index.js file. So, I don't have a separate plugins.js file for the plugins, but I know that all plugin-related stuff is located in index.js of each store module subfolder, and that is good enough for me.